# Undefined variable $submit

Tags: php, mysql, variables, undefined

I'm getting an error which states:
Notice: Undefined variable: submit on line 4. I have no clue why since I have defined it with the submit button? Can someone please explain why? Don't really see the problem here.

```
<?php

                if($submit)
                {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO personnel (first, last, username, department, email) VALUES ('$first','$last','$username','$department','$email')";
                $add = mysql_query($sql);
                echo "<div class='confirmation-box round'>Thank you! New user have been added</div>";
                }
                else
                {
                ?>
                <form method="post" action="useradd.php">

                    <fieldset>

                    <p>
                        <label for="simple-input">Firstname</label>
                        <input type="text" id="first" name="firstname" class="round default-width-input" />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="simple-input">Lastname</label>
                        <input type="text" id="last" name="lastname" class="round default-width-input" />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="simple-input">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="round default-width-input" />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="simple-input">Department</label>
                        <input type="text" id="department" name="department" class="round default-width-input" />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="simple-input">Email</label>
                        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="round default-width-input" />
                    </p>
                        <input type="Submit" name="submit" class="button round blue image-right ic-add text-upper" value="Add">

                    </fieldset>

                </form>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
```

(Sorry for stupid question, kinda new at php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical old school case of `register_globals` usage. It decides whether or not register the EGPCS (Environment, GET, POST, Cookie, Server) variables as global variables. Nobody does that anymore.

Change it to this:

```
if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
```

Comment: Thank you, This worked. Another problem that now showed is that all my SQL inserts is apparently undefined as well on line 5, which is: $sql = "INSERT INTO personnel (first, last, username, department, email) VALUES ('$first','$last','$username','$department','$email')";

Comment: Yep, same solution applies. What might help is to use an IDE that will alert you of unfavorable coding practices. I personally like PHPStorm.

Answer (score 0):

> I have no clue why since I have defined it with the submit button

No you did not.

The first instance of `$submit` which is `if($submit)` means:

```
If $submit is TRUE
```

... `$submit` has never been defined before.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
//code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check post  with following code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
//Here will be your code
}
```

try this

And good practice to give proper name to submit button. Ex. 'cmdSubmit'

Best luck

Answer (score 0):

Its a warning not an error.
You can just declare the varible with empty value or some default value.